# Can we get an more options when flagging something as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I tried flagging a post as off-topic.  When I drilled down through the reasons for flagging it, I wasn't given an option that was suitable.

[This was the question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/30964/12420) which is clearly not about DIY.  I flagged it as off-topic and then selected that the question belongs on another site on StackExchange.  However, I was only presented with this Meta site.  I didn't think it belonged here either.  Can we add other options here?  Or maybe a generic reason why we think it is off-topic?

Answer (score 2):

This is up to SE, so you'd need to discuss on MSO. At present, the list is only populated with the most popularly migrated sites, and we haven't reached the threshold for any of those to appear yet. See [this question on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96013/off-topic-site-list) for more details.

Until then, simply flag the question as "off topic because of X" or just "needs moderator attention", and we'll have a look at it.

Comment: Don't all users get the [search box](http://imgur.com/eincHma)? Maybe it's just a moderator/trusted user option.

Comment: Nope, the search box only appears for moderators.

Comment: ------Lame------

Comment: Old question, I know, but I just had such a flag marked as declined with the message "Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?". The decline is fine, as it may have belonged where it was, but I did use the 'needs mod attention' flag, which according to this answer, is the "standard" flag for this situation.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. I think you can just ask. Just send them a message to the Junta in the TL and they'll get it done https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1450/5778 (you can ask for that list). Don't forget the secret handshake, and the secret cult incantation.