# Vote to Close - different site - add sites?

Tags: discussion, support

I just added a Vote to Close [How to make a DIY video player?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/167610/how-to-make-a-diy-video-player) As I have found in the past, the only option for "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" is https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com So instead I selected "Other".

What is the process for adding other sites to "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"? Just off the top of my head, some that have been appropriate at times include:

- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/
- https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/
- https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/
- https://gardening.stackexchange.com/

and there are probably a few others that would be reasonable to have available as choices.

I just found this:

[Can we get an more options when flagging something as off-topic?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/842/can-we-get-an-more-options-when-flagging-something-as-off-topic?rq=1)

from several years ago. So this is not a new problem. Is there a solution?

Comment: There was an answer posted on the previous question. I'm not aware of any changes since then. As mentioned in that answer, this is a question for MSO.

Comment: Arghh! I started searching around a bit in MSO. This has been an ongoing complaint for several years. With no apparent solution in sight.